# No one can edit post/pages by Administrator

Tags: users, capabilities

With edit_others_posts and edit_others_pages, I know it will give a user role (e.g. Editor) to edit anyone's posts/pages. However, I will like to restrict the capability to edit posts/pages created by any Administrators.

Example, Editor can edit anyone's posts/pages except Administrators'. Only Administrators can edit their own posts/pages.

Any help or advice?

Answer (score 0):

Download User Role Editor and uncheck the edit others post [image]

Comment: Thanks but I think I didn't make it clear. I will like to allow Editor to edit others post but NOT administrators' posts.